# Instalar MongoDB em outra unidade no Windows

Tags: mongodb

Estou tentando instalar o MongoDB em outra unidade que não seja a "C".

Entretanto ao tentar utilizar o comando "mongo" no terminal o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Failed to connect to localhost:27017

Os exemplos que encontro só falam em "C:". Como configurar o MongoDB para funcionar em outra unidade?

Quero que fique da seguinte maneira:

- E:\programas\mongodb
- E:\programas\mongodb\data\db

Isso é possível ou só permite instalação na unidade de instalação do Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui instalar o MongoDB.

Criei dentro da pasta "mongodb" as pastas "logs" e "data/db" e depois executei o seguinte comando:

> e:\programas\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --logpath "e:\programas\mongodb\logs\server.log" --dbpath "e:\programas\mongodb\data\db" --install

Além de mudar o directório, instalei o serviço "MongoDB" evitando ter que abrir o pront.